# Include file in PHP form show error and content of included file

Tags: php

I have included php class file which contains all the classes as

But in output it is showing content of classes.php file and fatal error class not found here i only want to use the classes written in "classes/classes.php".But it is showing contents of this file in output.
please help me,i have tried all the ways.
Thank U in advance.

Comment: How are you including the file? `include()` and `require()` should read in the code and execute it. `readfile()` and the like will treat it as plain text for output with no execution

Comment: can u post a lil bit of code in your q?

Comment: your confusing us with "psychic overflow" where they can read your code without you providing it...

Comment: if you provide some source we can help you to check for syntax errors.
a few quick steps: * make sure file exists with file_exists before including it * use `include()` or `require()` to

Answer (score 2):

Be carefull if you haven't put the php start tag ( `<?php` ) in classes/classes.php file.

It's not a joke, it's an usual error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to include a few pages in my PHP script and at first, they would print the contents of the file to the web page.  I had forgotten to include the php qualifiers.  Make sure your include page has the  tags surrounding your code.